# Why the word "українська" in these two phrases has different endings?

Tags: прикметники

Why is the pronunciation of “Ukrainian” in *“Я розмовляю українською.”*  (I speak Ukrainian.) different from the pronunciation of “Ukrainian” in *“Я розумію українську.”* (I understand Ukrainian)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is because of the **Adjective cases** with Hard Declension (`-ий`).

The first sentence has verb *розмовляти* (to speak) which governs the **Instrumental case** (with/using what?) — *українськ**ою***.

The second sentence has verb розуміти (to understand) which governs the **Accusative case** (a direct object of action) — *українськ**у***.

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_grammar#Declension) contains further introductory information about the Adjective cases in the Ukrainian language.

Just in case, adjective *українська* is feminine because it is for the noun *мова* (language) which is feminine and optional in speech. And, yes, nouns also have the same Cases (more information in [other paragraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_grammar#Nouns)) with their own declensions.